# How do I ensure DelegatingHandlers throw exceptions on timeouts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm using [HttpClient's PostAnsyc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync(v=vs.118).aspx) method to synchronously call a REST API from service code invoked by my MVC application, but I'm losing exceptions in a DelegatingHandler.

The usage is synchronous. I am aware of the async path and it does not fit my use case.

Here are some variant's I've tried that didn't throw exceptions on timeout:

```
//controller action
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Foo(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var result = _businessService.Foo(id);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        return Json(exception, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
}

//infrastructure code deep in my application
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Uri uri, StringContent content)
{
    return _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
}

//DelegatingHandler code
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith( t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                if(t.Exception != null)
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(t.Exception);
                }
            }
            else if (t.IsCanceled)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    LogResponse(t.Result);
                    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(t.Result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(ex);
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

How do I ensure that my DelegatingHandlers do not swallow exceptions during a timeout?

Comment: I found that the DelegatingHandler was eating my exceptions. Updated the question to reflect my actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(Uri uri, StringContent content)
{
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellation.Token);
    var timeout = Task.Delay(5000);
    await Task.WhenAny(task, timeout);
    if(timeout.IsCompleted)
    {
        cancellation.Cancel();
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
    else
        return await task;
}
```

This example would provide a timeout of 5 seconds before try to cancel the POST operation and throw a timeout exception.

Unfortunately the `HttpClient` has no synchronous methods, so whatever you do another thread pool thread is taking care of the request and you have to wait for it.

An alternative is to use the [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx), but it is less fancy and you have to serialize your payload yourself (which is not big deal with the NewtonSoft Json library)

Comment: I'm fine waiting for `HttpClient`, my question is how do I do that while not waiting forever if there was a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty trivial to create a timeout using a `CancellationTokenSource`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(Uri uri, StringContent content)
{
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(5000); // Cancel after 5 seconds.
    return await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellation.Token);
}
```